# post from tpl file to the controller in codeigniter without ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and smarty and I am new at these.

I have a tpl file in views folder and a controller connected to this tpl file. 
this is my tpl file:

```
  <form name="input" action="register" method="post" name="registerform">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" name="registersubmit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

and in the controller i am trying to print it out in 2 different ways

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($this->input->post('user'));
```

the output:

```
array (size=0) empty
boolean false
```

So I always get false or empty when i use the action=[control name]. I don't know what is the problem maybe you guys can help me.
Am I allowed to use regular form tags in a tpl file? or must i use smarty form tags like {form url='register'} ? I saw many ajax example about this but is it possible to post some data without ajax?

Comment: I have'nt worked with codeigniter but I have with smarty. Should'nt the action of the form be register.php? the script you are wanting to POST to. With smarty you can use any HTML you wish with <!-- PHP --> embedded code. So you may use regular form tags

Comment: what is the name of function you have `var_dump()` function? you need to append it's name to the controller name in the action prop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it was a .htaccess problem. thanks guys anyway.